# setMonth and getMonth does not return the same value

Tags: javascript, date

When I write this, I get the following problem:

```
const date = new Date();
date.setMonth(5);
date.getMonth(); // returns 6

date.setMonth(4);
date.getMonth(); // returns 4
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not occurring every time, only if you try it on a date, when the current day is the 31th of the month.

So today this is 2018. May 31.

When you set the month which is not a 31 day long month, then the day is overflowing, and the month is automatically increased by 1.

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); // 4 31
date.setMonth(5);
console.log(date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); // 6 1
```